# cycles permutation random probability

Tags: probability, combinatorics

How to show the following;

Using

$1 + \sum_{ n \geq 1} \frac {u^{n}}{n!} \sum_{\pi \in S_n} \Pi_{i}x_{i}^{N_i(\pi)} =
\Pi_{m\geq1} \exp(u^m x_m / m)$ where $N_i(\pi)$ is the number of length $i$ cycles 
of a permutation $\pi$ on $n$-symbols

compute the expected number 
of $j$ cycles of a random permutation $\pi$.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: This is a rare case where hyphens can make a difference in meaning. I suspect that you mean the number of $j$-cycles, i.e. the number of cycles of length $j$?

Comment: The question can't be answered in its present form because you haven't specified a distribution. Presumably the random permutation is to be chosen uniformly from among some set of permutations? If so, which set? All permutations on a certain number of symbols?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll assume that you're asking about the expected number of $j$-cycles in a permutation uniformly randomly selected among all permutations on $n$ symbols.

Your equation relates to expressions for a generating function in which the coefficient of the term $u^n\prod_ix_i^{k_i}/n!$ counts the number of permutations on $n$ symbols with $k_i$ cycles of length $i$. The expected number of $j$-cycles in a uniformly random permutation on $n$ symbols is the sum of the numbers of $j$-cycles in all such permutations divided by the number $n!$ of all such permutations, and we get that by summing over the coefficients times the number $k_j$ of $j$-cycles. Thus the desired expected number is

$$
\begin{align}
[u^n]\left.\frac{\partial}{\partial x_j}\prod_{m\ge1}\mathrm e^{u^mx_m/m}\right|_{x_k=1}
&=
[u^n]\frac{u^j}j\left.\prod_{m\ge1}\mathrm e^{u^mx_m/m}\right|_{x_k=1}
\\
&=
[u^n]\frac{u^j}j\prod_{m\ge1}\mathrm e^{u^m/m}
\\
&=
[u^n]\frac{u^j}j\mathrm e^{\sum_{m\ge1}u^m/m}
\\
&=
[u^n]\frac{u^j}j\mathrm e^{-\log(1-u)}
\\
&=
[u^n]\frac{u^j}j\frac1{1-u}
\\
&=\begin{cases}
1/j&j\le n\;,\\
0&j\gt n\;.
\end{cases}
\\
\end{align}
$$

Thus the expected number of $j$-cycles in a permutation on $n$ symbols is $1/j$, unless $j\gt n$, in which case it is of course zero.

Note that this result can be more easily obtained directly: There are $(j-1)!$ ways of arranging $j$ given symbols in a cycle, $(n-j)!$ permutations of the remaining symbols and $n!$ permutations in total, so the probability for $j$ given symbols to form a cycle in a permutation randomly uniformly chosen among all permutations of $n$ symbols is

$$
\frac{(j-1)!(n-j)!}{n!}\;.
$$

There are $\displaystyle\binom nj$ selections of $j$ out of $n$ symbols, so the expected number of $j$-cycles is

$$
\binom nj\frac{(j-1)!(n-j)!}{n!}=\frac1j\;.
$$

Since the result doesn't depend on $n$ as long as $n\ge j$, one could in a certain sense say that the expected number of $j$-cycles in *any* random permutation, of unspecified length, is $1/j$, namely in the sense that the expected number of $j$-cycles in a permutation uniformly randomly chosen among all permutations on at most $n$ symbols goes to $1/j$ as $n\to\infty$; since you didn't specify a distribution, perhaps this is the result you were aiming at?

Comment: joriki what is the $[u^n]$ notation what does it mean? Thank you..

Comment: @Salih: $[u^n]f(u)$ is the coefficient of $u^n$ in the power series for $f(u)$.

Comment: Joriki what is the power series expansion of the last expression could you write it in open form? is u between 0 and 1 so that that fraction is an infinite sum? Thank you

Comment: @Salih: Generating functions are treated as [formal power series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_power_series); one doesn't usually worry about their radius of convergence or substitute values into them (though that's not always true). The series for $1/(1-u)$ is $\sum_{k=0}^\infty u^k$, so the entire series is $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}u^{k+j}/j$.